# Handling an exception in pl/sql

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am using Oracle Forms 10g to build a GUI that adds a user to the db by filling a form. The following is the code that I used on the `when-button-pressed` trigger on the `Add User` button:

**code:**

```
declare
    firstname VARCHAR(15);
    lastname VARCHAR(15);
    usernameee VARCHAR(15);
    emailll VARCHAR(15);
    pass1 VARCHAR(15);
    pass2 VARCHAR(15);
    v varchar2(200);
begin
    firstname := :HOMEADMIN1.TXTFIRSTNAME;
    lastname := :HOMEADMIN1.TXTLASTNAME;
    usernameee := :HOMEADMIN1.TXTUSERNAME;
    emailll := :HOMEADMIN1.TXTEMAIL;
    pass1 := :HOMEADMIN1.TXTPASSWORD;
    pass2 := :HOMEADMIN1.TXTPASSWORD2;

    if firstname is null or lastname is null or usernameee is null or 
        emailll is null or pass1 is null or pass2 is null then
        message('Please fill all fields');
    else
        select Firstname into v from Person where Username = usernameee;
        if sql%found then
            message('This username is already taken');
        else
            select Firstname into v from Person where Email = emailll;
            if sql%found then
                message('This email is already taken');
            else
                insert into Person values (PersonSeq.nextval,firstname,lastname,usernameee,pass1,emailll,0,1);
                commit;
            end if;
        end if;
    end if;
end;
```

This code checks if all inputs `textboxes` are filled (which works), then it must check if the `username` and `email` that are entered are already taken or not. The code compiles well, but when I enter any `email` or `username` I get an `error 01403` which indicates that I must handle a `NO_DATA_FOUND exception`.
Can you tell me how can I do that in my code here? I am stuck because I have 2 conditions (queries) that should be handled and I don't know how. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lines you're interested in are SELECT statements that fetch "Firstname" (with different conditions - once by username, then by email).

One approach is to use aggregate function, such as MAX:

```
select max(Firstname) into v from Person where Username = usernameee;
```

Doing so, it won't raise NO-DATA-FOUND.

However, that's just a *nice* workaround. Correct approach would be handling exceptions properly. In order to do that, you'll need to enclose those SELECT statements into their own BEGIN-EXCEPTION-END blocks, such as:

```
else
  -- First, check whether USERNAME is taken:
  begin
    select firstname into v from person where username = usernameee;

    -- You don't need IF SQL%FOUND because - if SELECT returned a value, you'll
    -- get here anyway
    message('This username is already taken');
    raise form_trigger_failure;   --> this is Forms, isn't it?

    exception
    -- SELECT returned nothing and raised an exception
    when no_data_found then 
      -- do nothing; proceed to EMAIL validation
      null;
  end;

  -- Username is available (because previous RAISE didn't fire
  begin
    select firstname into v from person where email = emailll;

    message('This email is already taken');
    raise form_trigger_failure;

  exception
    when no_data_found then
      null; 
  end;

  insert into person values (...);
  commit;
end if;
```

Comment: Well, it is a matter of taste to handle "normal" behavior (finding no rows seems to be the default) as "EXCEPTION". Thus I would prefer the first solution.

Comment: if I want to use the first solution what should be the condition just after the select statement?

Comment: If you use MAX, then code you posted in the initial message stays "as is", no changes - you'd only add MAX into SELECT statements.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the solution @Littlefoot offered you could split out  each validation to it's own separate procedure. The main process then has very little logic. Validate the requirements and insert or just handle requirement exceptions. So:

```
declare
    -- internal exceptions 
    not_all_fields_entered  exception; 
    user_name_already_taken exception; 
    email_already_taken     exception; 

    -- variables
    firstname VARCHAR(15);
    lastname VARCHAR(15);
    usernameee VARCHAR(15);
    emailll VARCHAR(15);
    pass1 VARCHAR(15);
    pass2 VARCHAR(15);

    -- validaion routines
    procedure validate_fields_entered
    is
    begin 
        if firstname is null or lastname is null or usernameee is null  
        or emailll is null or pass1 is null or pass2 is null  
        then
            raise not_all_fields_entered;
        end if;
    end validate_fields_entered; 

    procedure validate_user_name_not_taken
    is 
        user_name_count integer; 
    begin 
         select count(*) 
           into user_name_count
           from Person 
          where Username = usernameee
            and rownum < 2;
        if user_name_count = 1  
        then 
           raise user_name_already_taken;
        end if;
    end validate_user_name_not_taken; 

    procedure validate_email_not_taken
    is 
        email_use_count integer; 
    begin 
         select count(*) 
           into email_use_count
           from Person 
          where Email = emailll
            and rownum < 2;
        if email_use_count = 1  
        then 
           raise email_already_taken;
        end if;
    end validate_user_name_not_taken;     

begin
    firstname := :HOMEADMIN1.TXTFIRSTNAME;
    lastname := :HOMEADMIN1.TXTLASTNAME;
    usernameee := :HOMEADMIN1.TXTUSERNAME;
    emailll := :HOMEADMIN1.TXTEMAIL;
    pass1 := :HOMEADMIN1.TXTPASSWORD;
    pass2 := :HOMEADMIN1.TXTPASSWORD2;

    -- do validations
    validate_fields_entered;
    validate_user_name_not_taken;
    validate_email_not_taken;

    -- all good insert the row 
    insert into Person values (PersonSeq.nextval,firstname,lastname,usernameee,pass1,emailll,0,1);

exception 
    when not_all_fields_entered  then 
         message('Please fill all fields');
    when user_name_already_taken then  
         message('This username is already taken');
    when email_already_taken then  
          message('This email is already taken');
    when others then 
         log_error (....) ; 
         raise ;
end;
```

I know it's not specified here but think Maintenance. What's needed if requirements change like: 
1. If it's not taken validate the format of the email is correct.
2. Validate the passwords are the same and satisfy complexity rules.